# Show div2 under div1 on mobil browsers - css: flex,

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two div, which is displayed correctly on the destop computer. But on mobile browser they do not look nice.

How can I get div2 to be under div1 in mobile browser(not on samme line)?

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.itemcontainer {

    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="flexcontainer itemcontainer ">

<div id="div1" style="border:1px solid blue; width:280px; height:300px; margin-right:auto;"> Yessss </div>
<div id="div2" style="border:1px solid blue; width:280px; height:300px; margin-left:auto">No</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: When they wrap , should they keep their width at 280px? .. and horizontal alignment, centered, left or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .flexcontainer{
    flex-direction : column;    
  }
}
```

just change the flex-direction to column in mobile view.

You can practice and understand Flexbox from this website :
https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0):

**First:** the closing tag for parent `div` is below the closing tag for `body` fix this
**Second:** add this css snippet to your code

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .flexcontainer {
        display:block;
        width: auto;
    }
    #div1, #div2 {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

let me know if this is what you are looking for